# How to install postgres10 tools on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to use `pg_dump` for postgres 10.4 on my EC2 instance. My AMI version is:

`$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03`

I've tried to get it from this repo: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm, then install postgres tools by command `sudo yum install postgres10` but it works only for Amazon Linux 2.

Do you have any idea how can I get Postgres10 for my instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any existing packages for version 10, here is how I compiled the client tools myself on the 2018.03 AMI

```
sudo yum install -y gcc readline-devel zlib-devel

wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v10.4/postgresql-10.4.tar.gz
tar -xf postgresql-10.4.tar.gz
cd postgresql-10.4

./configure
make -C src/bin
sudo make -C src/bin install

make -C src/include
sudo make -C src/include install

make -C src/interfaces
sudo make -C src/interfaces install

make -C doc
sudo make -C doc install
```

After this you can run `pg_dump` from `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_dump` or alternatively add `/usr/local/pgsql/bin` to your `PATH` to run `pg_dump` anywhere

Comment: Thank you. I've found binaries here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and if I download and run them, it also works.